# Azure Storage SAS token working on localhost but not when deployed on Azure Kubernetes

Tags: javascript, python, azure, kubernetes, azure-storage

I am uploading and downloading files to Azure storage from a React spa using SAS tokens.

When running on localhost, everything works, however when deployed to Kubernetes on Azure, I receive the following authentication error.

```
onError RestError: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:e6bfca97-c01e-0030-2e29-4e7d7c000000
Time:2020-06-29T15:26:39.7164613Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was w

2020-06-29T20:26:39Z
/blob/datalake/container/Natural_Language_Processing.pdf
```

The javascript code responsible for the upload is

```js
// upload to Azure
const blobName = file.name;
const accountSas = resp.data.SAS;
const account = resp.data.account;
const containerName = resp.data.container;
const anonymousCredential = new AnonymousCredential();
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
    `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net?${accountSas}`,
    anonymousCredential
);
// Create a container
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(
    containerName
);
// Create a blob
const content = file;
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(
    content,
    Buffer.byteLength(content)
);
```

while the backend Python code for the SAS token generation is the following

```py
if content['up_down'] == 'download':
    permission = BlobSasPermissions(read=True)
else:
    permission = BlobSasPermissions(write=True)

account_name = os.getenv("STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME")
container_name = metadata.get_container_name()
blob_name = content['filePath']
expiry = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=5)

options = {
    'account_name': account_name,
    'container_name': container_name,
    'blob_name': blob_name,
    'account_key': os.getenv("STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY"),
    'permission': permission,
    'expiry': expiry
}

SAS = generate_blob_sas(**options)
```

Where [`generate_blob_sas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob?view=azure-python#generate-blob-sas-account-name--container-name--blob-name--snapshot-none--account-key-none--user-delegation-key-none--permission-none--expiry-none--start-none--policy-id-none--ip-none----kwargs-) is imported from azure-storage-blob (version 12.3.1).

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: I noticed that there's an IP address (`84.71.57.183`) involved however I didn't see that in the `options`. Could that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Thank you @Gaurav Mantri-AIS for your help.
At the beginning I tried without specifying the client ip but still not working.
After that I tried specifying the client ip when asking for the sas token (not included in the Python snippet above) but still no luck with it.

Comment: How are you accessing the `STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY` on your local? Are you also passing the `STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY ` to your kubernetes pod of the `backend-service`?

Comment: Thank you @Dhruv Shah for the help.
The `STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY` is passed as a secret in Kubernetes and loaded as environmental variable. Just to see if this was the error, I am temporarily returning the `STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY` as part of the response from the API and it matches

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code for generate_blod_sas method?

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri-AIS. 
[`generate_blob_sas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob?view=azure-python#generate-blob-sas-account-name--container-name--blob-name--snapshot-none--account-key-none--user-delegation-key-none--permission-none--expiry-none--start-none--policy-id-none--ip-none----kwargs-) is imported from azure.storage.blob (version 12.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

After a long time scratching my head to find a solution, I figured out where the problem was.

It had nothing to do with the Python library for accessing the blob, but rather with the environment variables in the Kubernetes pod.

The environment variables were passed to Kubernetes as secrets using a yaml file (as explained in this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#creating-a-secret-manually)).
Using this method, the secret needs to be base64 encoded. For this I was using the following

```sh
echo 'secret' | base64
>> c2VjcmV0Cg==
```

In this way however, the `echo` command appends by default a newline character to the output. What I should have used instead was

```sh
echo -n 'secret' | base64
>> c2VjcmV0
```

This bug was particularly difficult to find especially because when printed, the wrong solution would appear to lead to the correct result

```sh
echo 'secret' | base64 | base64 -d
>> secret
```

Anyway, I hope that my mistake will help someone in the future!